# Deleting records through PHP without the page being reloaded (using AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to delete some records from a database table through PHP without the page being reloaded (using AJAX). First I am printing all the information in a table and then the user can click a `delete` button, which will delete the record. However, I am having troubles with passing the record `id` to the AJAX method.

```
ListProducts.php

create connection
...
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<table border = '1' style = 'border-collapse:collapse;'>";
echo "<tr><th>UserID</th><th>Username</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['username']."</td><td><input type = 'submit' onclick = 'delete_record()' value = 'Delete' id = '".$row['id']."'></td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Then, within the same page, there is the AJAX function. I have given each `input` field the corresponding id and I am trying to pick it with jQuery

```
function delete_rekord(){
    var id = "Default";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").click(function(){
            id = $(this).attr('id');
        });
    });
    alert(id); //Test; will print DEFAULT
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            alert("Deleted user with ID: " + this.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?id="+id, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Over at `delete.php` I just delete the record and print the id of the deleted record which I collect in this function as a responseText and print out a message. I have put a test `alert(id)` and it seems that the value of `var id` is 
staying default, just as I initialize it. So the mistake must be in the way I am retrieving the id through jQuery. Any ideas how to resolve this? 

 Thanks

Comment: You can't get id value from document ready function. That's by its always show DEFAULT value.

Comment: You should take your remaining code inside document ready.

Comment: I edited your question now check it work or not?

Comment: `function delete_rekord(){
    var id = "Default";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").click(function(){
            id = $(this).attr('id');
        });
    });` this is a mess - effectively you have one event handler inside another. Do you understand what this code is doing? I suspect not. Either use inline event handlers or use jQuery style unobtrusive event handlers. Don't mix and match, and certainly don't put both on the same element to handle the same event - very confusing. Also you might find jQuery $.ajax easier to use than native XHR.

Comment: @rawathemant re your (currently pending) edit: You should not edit the **question** for the purpose of demonstrating a potential solution - that way no-one can see the original problem and the question text makes no sense. If you think you can fix it, copy the code into an **Answer**, change it to make it work and then post an answer. Also that way you can get upvotes / answer acceptance etc. I think actually you already have enough reputation that you ought to understand this by now anyway. Please withdraw your edit. Thankyou.

Comment: @ADyson it's not possible to withdrawal edit.

Comment: @rawathemant In that case I suggest you amend your edit to such effect that it puts the code back the way it was originally, and say so in your edit comment, so that reviewers understand. Perhaps you can leave in some minor improvement to the wording of the question, or the code formatting or something, if you can think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the $row['id'] into your javascript function like below. In your html change the code as below

```
<input type = 'submit' onclick = 'delete_record(".$row['id'].")' value = 'Delete' id = '".$row['id']."'>
```

In your javascript, change the function like this

```
function delete_rekord(rowid){

   var id = rowid;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: So obvious, thanks. But it seems that I have to reload the page in order to see the changes (in the printed table). Did I do something wrong with AJAX?

Comment: your ajax deals with only deleting the record without page submit/refresh. in order to effect the table with deleted records you need to refresh the page. OR you can hide the respective table row after ajax call, so that it will look like the record got deleted from the table.

Answer (score 2):

You should pas the `id` variable into the delete function

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['username']."</td><td><input type='submit' onclick='delete_record(".$row['id']."); return false;' value = 'Delete' id = '".$row['id']."'></td></tr>";`
```

in your js

```
function delete_record(id){ // also rename it to delete_record your fn name was delete_rekord
  alert(id); //Test; will print the correct ID
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        alert("Deleted user with ID: " + this.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?id="+id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value of Id as function parameter

```
<input type ='submit' onclick = 'delete_record(".$row['id'].")' value = 'Delete' id = '".$row['id']."'>

function delete_record(id){
    alert(id);
}
```